# PAGE_GUARD protection on stack pages but exception handler is not executed

Tags: c, windows, exception, winapi, memory

I am adding the `PAGE_GUARD` protection to pages of the current thread's stack via `VirtualProtect`. However, on accessing the stack, the exception handler I have installed is never executed.

I assume the OS just silently swallows the Guard-Page-Violation Exceptions because it uses guard pages to manage stack growth and stack overflows.

Is it in this case possible to catch these exceptions at all ?

Here is my C-code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>

LONG WINAPI BlanketExceptionHandler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) {

    printf("exception code: %lx\n", ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode);
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main(void) {

    // Install exception handler
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(BlanketExceptionHandler);

    ULONG_PTR stackBot = 0, stackTop = 0;   

    GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(&stackBot, &stackTop);
    assert(stackBot < stackTop);

    // turn all pages in the stack into guard-pages
    DWORD savedProtect = 0;
    if(!VirtualProtect((LPVOID) stackBot, stackTop - stackBot, PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &savedProtect)){
        fprintf(stderr, "[Error]: Could not add guard pages: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // access some stack memory page. This should trigger the registered exception handler!
    *(DWORD*) (stackTop - 0x1500) = 0xdeadbeef;

    return 0;
}
```

Code needs to be compiled with

```
cl /nologo main.c /link /STACK:0x100000,0x100000
```

Running the code gives no output from the `BlanketExceptionHandler`. But, using `VirtualQuery`, I have observed that the stack pages have the correct protections.

I have also tried installing the exception handler through `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` but that did not work either.

Comment: "*the OS ... uses guard pages to manage stack growth and stack overflows*" - only when the exception occurs in a guard page that is actually created by the OS, not by any arbitrary guard page that is created by user code. See [A closer look at the stack guard page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220203-00/?p=106215), ie: "*The default exception handler deals with the exception by **looking to see if the address lies in the current stack’s guard page region**. If so, then it upgrades the next reserved page to a guard page, and then resumes execution.*"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I have stated in my initial post `AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, BlanketExceptionHandler);` does not work either.

Comment: won't pretend to know the answer; but if you guarded your entire stack, how do you imagine the exception handler will be called? you need some stack to make the call and execute its code.

Comment: @LouisKronberg "*as I have stated in my initial post `AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, BlanketExceptionHandler);` does not work either*" - Sorry, I didn't see that part when reading your question.

Comment: @YakovGalka That is actually an interesting idea. Though, if the exception handler really has  problems because of the stack guards on the other pages then I would have expected the program to crash or at least complain in some way under a debugger. I'll look into this more. Disclaimer: I have very superficial understanding of the exception handling.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *that is actually created by the OS, not by any arbitrary guard page that is created by user* - page not containing information who set page_guard flag. for instance [`_resetstkoflw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/resetstkoflw?view=msvc-170) set `PAGE_GUARD`.. kernel auto handle guard exception if it in range of current user stack. it also adjust `StackLimit` in `NT_TIB` during this

Comment: *OS just silently swallows the Guard-Page-Violation Exceptions* - true. if it in range of current thread user mode stack. in your code , in usual case - `VirtualProtect` must already fail, because no memory yet allocated at `stackBot` but because you set stackcommit==stacklimit - this work. and then guard reset by system already on VirtualProtect api exit, because you set this on all stack

Comment: *Is it in this case possible to catch these exceptions at all ?* - no. but for what you want do this at all ?

Comment: @RbMm "*page not containing information who set page_guard flag*" - true, but the OS knows WHERE its guard page is located on the stack. So it knows if the guard page fault happens in a guard page that it had reserved for stack management. "*kernel auto handle guard exception if it in range of current user stack*" - I would be very worried if the kernel is manipulating the stack on *any* guard page fault that occurs anywhere on the stack, rather than on just the reserved guard page.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - really i check now - os handle guard exception if it occur in **any** place of the current thread stack. even if it higer that current esp/rsp. so checks not very strict

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *I would be very worried if the kernel is manipulating the stack on any guard page fault that occurs anywhere on the stack, rather than on just the reserved guard page* - but you can check this.. may be not very logic, but as is

Comment: @RbMm "*but you can check this..*" - maybe YOU can, but I can't. I'm not THAT talented to dig deep into OS internals, like you are.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i check.. it. this is realy work. os even set `StackLimit` to incorrect value (higer that current rsp) if guard exception was in area higer that rsp.

Comment: and here not need dig to os at all, i mean simply write test code.. now i simply can not write good example becase not at working comp, but can check with debugger

Comment: i be do next test - first call `void* p = alloca(0x10000)` for allocate 64kb in stack. than set `PAGE_GUARD` to `BYTE* q = (PBYTE)p+0x8000` address. say 2 pages. then access `q` address (say `*q=0`). look memory map before and after this. and look for `StackLimit` before and after `*q = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it in this case possible to catch these exceptions at all ?

no. if you access guard page, exception (as any exception) first will be handle by kernel code. if exception ocur in current thread stack range - the kernel handler remove `PAGE_GUARD` from page, where exeception was, ensure that bellow this page - several `PAGE_GUARD` exist and adjust `StackLimit := PAGE_ALIGN(MemmoryAccessAddress)` in `NT_TIB` (you can check this). and not call user mode exception handlers (if this not the last page in stack)

---

code example:

```
PCSTR GetStateSz(ULONG State)
{
    switch (State)
    {
    case MEM_FREE: return "FREE";
    case MEM_COMMIT: return "COMMIT";
    case MEM_RESERVE: return "RESERVE";
    }
    return "?";
}

PCSTR GetTypeSz(ULONG Type)
{
    switch (Type)
    {
    case MEM_IMAGE: return "IMAGE";
    case MEM_MAPPED: return "MAPPED";
    case MEM_PRIVATE: return "PRIVATE";
    }
    return "?";
}

void FormatProtect(ULONG Protect, PSTR psz, ULONG cch)
{
    static const ULONG pp[] = { 
        PAGE_NOACCESS, 
        PAGE_READONLY, 
        PAGE_READWRITE, 
        PAGE_WRITECOPY, 
        PAGE_EXECUTE, 
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, 
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY,
        PAGE_GUARD,
        PAGE_NOCACHE,
        PAGE_WRITECOMBINE,
    };

    static const PCSTR ss[] = { 
        "NOACCESS", 
        "READONLY", 
        "READWRITE", 
        "WRITECOPY", 
        "EXECUTE", 
        "EXECUTE_READ",
        "EXECUTE_READWRITE",
        "EXECUTE_WRITECOPY",
        "GUARD",
        "NOCACHE",
        "WRITECOMBINE",
    };

    ULONG n = _countof(pp);

    do 
    {
        if (Protect & pp[--n])
        {
            int len = sprintf_s(psz, cch, " | %s", ss[n]);
            if (0 >= len)
            {
                break;
            }

            psz += len, cch -= len;
        }
    } while (n);
}

ULONG WINAPI PrintProtect_I(PVOID BaseAddress)
{
    PVOID AllocationBase = BaseAddress;
    ::MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    while (VirtualQuery(BaseAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) && 
        mbi.AllocationBase == AllocationBase)
    {
        CHAR szProtect[0x100];
        FormatProtect(mbi.Protect, szProtect, _countof(szProtect));
        DbgPrint("[%p, %p) [%X] %s %s { %s }\n", mbi.BaseAddress, 
            BaseAddress = (PBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize, 
            mbi.RegionSize >> PAGE_SHIFT, GetStateSz(mbi.State), GetTypeSz(mbi.Type), szProtect);
    }

    return 0;
}

void PrintProtect(PVOID BaseAddress)
{
    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, PrintProtect_I, BaseAddress, 0, 0))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    PNT_TIB tib = reinterpret_cast<PNT_TIB>(NtCurrentTeb());
    DbgPrint("[%p, %p) << Current Stack\n\n", tib->StackLimit, tib->StackBase);
}

ULONG WINAPI SetGuard(PVOID pv)
{
    ULONG op;
    return VirtualProtect(pv, PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD, &op);
}

void GDemo()
{
    PVOID stack = alloca(0x10000);
    PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)PAGE_ALIGN((PBYTE)stack + 0x8000);
    ULONG_PTR a, b;
    GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(&a, &b);
    DbgPrint("[%p, %p) << Stack Region\n\n", a, b);
    PrintProtect((PVOID)a);
    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, SetGuard, pb, 0, 0))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        PrintProtect((PVOID)a);
        *pb = 0;
        PrintProtect((PVOID)a);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
[000000EAAE4C0000, 000000EAAE5C0000) << Stack Region

[000000EAAE4C0000, 000000EAAE5AB000) [EB] RESERVE PRIVATE {  }
[000000EAAE5AB000, 000000EAAE5AE000) [3] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | GUARD | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5AE000, 000000EAAE5C0000) [12] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5AE000, 000000EAAE5C0000) << Current Stack

[000000EAAE4C0000, 000000EAAE5AB000) [EB] RESERVE PRIVATE {  }
[000000EAAE5AB000, 000000EAAE5AE000) [3] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | GUARD | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5AE000, 000000EAAE5B7000) [9] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B7000, 000000EAAE5B8000) [1] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | GUARD | EXECUTE_READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B8000, 000000EAAE5C0000) [8] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5AE000, 000000EAAE5C0000) << Current Stack

[000000EAAE4C0000, 000000EAAE5AB000) [EB] RESERVE PRIVATE {  }
[000000EAAE5AB000, 000000EAAE5AE000) [3] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | GUARD | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5AE000, 000000EAAE5B4000) [6] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B4000, 000000EAAE5B7000) [3] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | GUARD | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B7000, 000000EAAE5B8000) [1] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | EXECUTE_READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B8000, 000000EAAE5C0000) [8] COMMIT PRIVATE {  | READWRITE }
[000000EAAE5B7000, 000000EAAE5C0000) << Current Stack
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my Question! Is there a source where I can read up on this or does one need to reverse engineer that stuff?

Comment: @LouisKronberg - i not sure about where this can be read, but this can be reversed and thested. you can extend own tests, under debugger. look by code or some tools memory map of current process ( current stack region). look before and after memory access. how it changed. test `StackLimit` value after every access. simply test more for better understand